# ProjectScaffold Error on Linux Generating Documentation

Tags: unit-testing, build, f#

I have a [project based](https://github.com/Adron/sharpKataStringCalc) on ProjectScaffold and am trying to get a good build. Except I keep getting this error when it attempts to generate the documentation.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Time Report
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Target         Duration
------         --------
Clean          00:00:00.0034230
AssemblyInfo   00:00:00.0089835
Build          00:00:04.1197276
CopyBinaries   00:00:00.0032325
RunTests       00:00:00.4153411
CleanDocs      00:00:00.0002847
Total:         00:00:12.2516707
Status:        Failure
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) System.Exception: generating help documentation failed
  at FSI_0001.Build.generateHelp' (Boolean fail, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSI_0001.Build+clo@218-18.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit _arg1) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Fake.TargetHelper+targetFromTemplate@155[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget (Fake.TargetTemplate`1 target) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Troubleshooting so far:

I've done a search, specifically for that exception and I get this result - a [single google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=System.Exception%3A%20generating%20help%20documentation%20failed%20at%20FSI_0001.Build.generateHelp%27%20(Boolean%20fail%2C%20Boolean%20debug)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20FSI_0001.Build%2Bclo%40218-18.Invoke%20(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%20_arg1)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20Fake.TargetHelper%2BtargetFromTemplate%40155%5BMicrosoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%5D.Invoke%20(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%20unitVar0)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget%20(Fake.TargetTemplate%601%20target)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0&oq=System.Exception%3A%20generating%20help%20documentation%20failed%20at%20FSI_0001.Build.generateHelp%27%20(Boolean%20fail%2C%20Boolean%20debug)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20FSI_0001.Build%2Bclo%40218-18.Invoke%20(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%20_arg1)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20Fake.TargetHelper%2BtargetFromTemplate%40155%5BMicrosoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%5D.Invoke%20(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit%20unitVar0)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0%20at%20Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget%20(Fake.TargetTemplate%601%20target)%20%5B0x00000%5D%20in%20%3Cfilename%20unknown%3E%3A0&aqs=chrome..69i57.227j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). In that result that links [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold/issues/156) it appears that adding specific version pegs for some of the dependencies like this:

```
nuget FSharp.Formatting 2.8.0
nuget FSharpVSPowerTools.Core 1.7.0
```

It appeared to work for some people but did not work for me. I still get the same exact issue afterwards. Maybe I need to pull dependencies again? I'm unsure.

I'd like to do one of these two possible things:

1. Resolve the problem. This is of course ideal. :)
2. Somehow remove the documentation generator for the ProjectScaffold.

Executing the generate.fsx file I get the following result.

```
adron@ubuntu ~/C/sharpKataStringCalc> fsharpi docs/tools/generate.fsx 
Copying file: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/img/logo-template.pdn
Copying file: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/img/logo.png
Copying styles and scripts: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/content/style.css
Copying styles and scripts: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/content/style_light.css
Copying styles and scripts: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/content/tips.js
Copying styles and scripts: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/content/img/github-blue.png
Copying styles and scripts: /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/docs/output/content/img/github.png
```

I was able to run the document build based on Tomas' recommendations with this command:

```
fsharpi -d:HELP docs/tools/generate.fsx and fsharpi -d:REFERENCE docs/tools/generate.fsx
```

...and got the following error:

```
Processing the file 'docpage' failed
Source written to: '/tmp/tmp4a1e2cc4.tmp.cs'
Compilation errors:
 - error: (0, 0) Assembly `FakeLib, Version=3.35.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' references `FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version number than imported assembly `FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

System.Exception: Generating HTML failed.
  at FSharp.Literate.RazorRender.handleCompile[String] (System.String source, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2 f) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSharp.Literate.RazorRender.ProcessFileModel[IDictionary`2] (System.Type modelType, System.Object model, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 properties) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSharp.Literate.Templating.generateFile (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 references, System.String contentTag, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 templateOpt, System.String output, IEnumerable`1 layoutRoots) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSharp.Literate.Templating.processFile (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 references, FSharp.Literate.LiterateDocument doc, System.String output, FSharp.Literate.ProcessingContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSharp.Literate.Literate.ProcessScriptFile (System.String input, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 templateFile, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 output, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 format, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 formatAgent, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 prefix, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 compilerOptions, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 lineNumbers, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 references, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 fsiEvaluator, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 replacements, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 includeSource, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 layoutRoots, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 generateAnchors, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 assemblyReferences, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 customizeDocument) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Literate>.$Main+processScriptFile@184.Invoke (System.String file, System.String output) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.String,System.String].InvokeFast[Unit] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2 func, System.String arg1, System.String arg2) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Literate>.$Main.processDirectory@199 (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 format, Boolean processRecursive, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2 processScriptFile, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2 processMarkdown, System.String indir, System.String outdir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSharp.Literate.Literate.ProcessDirectory (System.String inputDirectory, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 templateFile, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 outputDirectory, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 format, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 formatAgent, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 prefix, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 compilerOptions, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 lineNumbers, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 references, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 fsiEvaluator, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 replacements, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 includeSource, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 layoutRoots, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 generateAnchors, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 assemblyReferences, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 processRecursive, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 customizeDocument) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FSI_0003.buildDocumentation () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@ () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

Comment: Can you run the code in `docs/tools/generate.fsx` from your F# Interactive? This should give you a more detailed error message...

Comment: The earlier error is fixed in the latest version of ProjectScaffold (the corrected version references F# Formatting using this line: https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold/blob/master/docs/tools/generate.template#L31 - you can make sure that your downloaded version has this...)

Comment: Just updated with the fsharpi execution of generate.fsx. It didn't come up with an error.

I also tried the second suggestion and it looks like I have the latest version. I did a one for one comparison merge and it's all synced up. Same issue.  :(

Comment: Can you try with `fsharpi -d:HELP docs/tools/generate.fsx` and `fsharpi -d:REFERENCE docs/tools/generate.fsx`? One of those (I suspect the second one) should throw a more detailed error.

Comment: Added the error to the issue above. Also got a build going here https://travis-ci.org/Adron/sharpKataStringCalc/builds/68259203 which is working, but locally I'm still getting errors. Any thoughts?  I'm still a bit confused by the messages.

Comment: Now this is interesting - and useful error report! Can you please open an issue for F# Formatting and we'll investigate there: https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/ (Please share the log you just added.)

Comment: Done, posted here: https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/issues/323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is were things got kind of interesting. I put everything back the way it was in the generate.fsx file and did a build. It broke, as I'd suspect with the error above. Then, by happenstance I noticed I needed to upgrade a number of things on Ubuntu 14.04 itself. So I clicked install and started downloading some 600+ MB of patches and updates. That finished, I had to reboot and the fs couldn't be mounted. So I went through a reboot, came into safe mode and let Ubuntu run a package rebuild for everything installed on the operating system. When that finished, I booted back up normally and launched Visual Studio Code and the bash to get back to work resolving this issue.

That's when I did a build and everything passed perfectly. Moral of the story, it appears that Ubuntu 14.04 needs the latest patches as well as insuring the latest mono is installed. It seems there must have been some mono dependency that was necessary for docs generation.

If you want to read more about the issue and what was done to resolve the issue check out this issue on Github: https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/issues/323